# Getting the first 10 characters of a string?

Tags: c, string

I have not been able to find any information with a web-search. Where should I be looking?

Comment: `man strncpy` here you go

Comment: @Ryan, Or leave it and mention that it's C++ since he might have meant that.

Comment: Avoid `strncpy`: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
char myString[256]; // Input string
char dest[256];     // Destination string

strncpy(dest, myString, 10);
dest[10] = 0; // null terminate destination
```

Comment: quick question, could I do strncpy(myString, myString,10) ?

Comment: if you want to truncate the string to 10 chars then put myString[10] = 0; (This given that myString points to memory and not a string lettral)

Comment: @user2341069 no you cant, as per the man page "The strings may not overlap, and the destination string dest must be large enough to receive the copy." As myString is a pointer to a char array in memory, using the same pointer twice means that they "overlap" in memory, and thus will cause an error. Essentially, this means that the src can not be a substring of dst or vice versa.

Comment: Is the null terminate character not '\0' rather than just a 0?

Comment: @TafT they are equivalent

Comment: @LefterisE Thank you.  It seems they are equivalent but '\0' is often used to indicate a character instead of a number.  This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955936/string-termination-char-c-0-vs-char-c-0 has a few sources in it.

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree: `strncpy()` has widely misunderstood semantics and is **very** error prone.  **DO NOT USE THIS FUNCTION**. Learn why here: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Answer (score 7):

```
char source[] = "abcdefthijklmn";
char target[100];

strncpy(target, source, 10);
target[10] = '\0'; // IMPORTANT!
```

Comment: @michaelb958 So what do I need to add or change?

Comment: target is not uninitialized pointer. target points to 100 bytes of memory in the stack. the \0 is not nessesary as strncpy will put it

Comment: @LefterisE Not sure about the initialization thing, but `strncpy` will not put a `'\0'` automatically

Comment: @LefterisE When I commented, the declaration was `char *target;`.

Comment: @michaelb958 Yes it was. Thank you. I'm a bit confused with `char *a` and `char a[100]`

Comment: i am confused aswell about how source is declared. maybe source should have been char* as it is a pointer to a string literal

Comment: @LefterisE I'm fairly sure that `char foo[] = "bar";` initialises `foo` with a copy of `"bar"`.

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree: `strncpy()` has widely misunderstood semantics and is **very** error prone.  **DO NOT USE THIS FUNCTION**. Learn why here: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Answer (score 4):

There are many different ways to achieve your goal:

- You can use `snprintf` (safest):

  ```
  char source[] = "abcdefthijklmn";
  char target[100];

  snprintf(target, sizeof target, "%.10s", source);
  ```
- You can use `strncat` if you know the destination has at least 11 elements:

  ```
  char source[] = "abcdefthijklmn";
  char target[100];

  *target = '\0';
  strncat(target, source, 10);
  ```
- You can use `strlen` and `memcpy` (same assumption about the size of destination):

  ```
  char source[] = "abcdefthijklmn";
  char target[100];
  size_t len = strlen(source);

  if (len > 10)
      len = 10;
  memcpy(target, source, len);
  target[len] = '\0';
  ```
- You can use a loop (same assumption about the size of destination):

  ```
  char source[] = "abcdefthijklmn";
  char target[100];
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      target[i] = source[i];
  }
  target[i] = '\0';
  ```
- [You could but **should not** use `strncpy()`](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/)

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the above answers:

```
char* someString = "your string goes here";

int main() 
{
  int n = 10;
  printf("(%.*s)\n", n, someString);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a good source, here's an example of an online man page you can use:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy

Important to note: you could also use memcpy instead of strncpy, but it requires you to add your own null-terminating byte.

Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

Hence, memcpy and strncpy work almost the same here, and memcpy is more efficient and less prone to error.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this.

```
   # include <stdio.h>
   # include <string.h>
   //Strings. String lenght terminator.
   //KHO2016.no1. mingw (TDM-GCC-32) . c-ansi .
   int main ()
   {
   //declare
   char src_str[20],dst_str[10];

   //valuate
   printf ("Enter a sentance of 20 letters\n");
   gets (src_str);
   strcpy (dst_str,src_str);

   //calculate
   dst_str [10] ='\0'; // from the "www.stack overflow"
   printf ("%s",dst_str);
   printf ("\n");

   //terminate
   return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/?kw=sprintf) with `.10` precision format:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{   
    char source[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char dest[11];
    memset(dest, '\0', sizeof(dest));

    sprintf(dest, "%.10s", source);

    printf("%s", dest); // abcdefghij
    return 0;
}
```