# String termination - char c=0 vs char c='\0'

Tags: c, string, c-strings, null-terminated, ansi-c

When terminating a string, it seems to me that logically `char c=0` is equivalent to `char c='\0'`, since the "null" (ASCII 0) byte is `0`, but usually people tend to do `'\0'` instead. Is this purely out of preference or should it be a better "practice"?

What is the preferred choice?

---

**EDIT:** ***K&R*** *says*: "The character constant `'\0'` represents the character with value zero, the null character. `'\0'` is often written instead of `0` to emphasize the character nature of some expression, but the numeric value is just `0`.

Comment: Hey Joe DF! Reading now K&R and had same question. Googled "\0 in c string" and second link is to your question. It helped me ;)

Comment: @vasili111 I'm glad it helped you. :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_control_code_chart

```
Binary   Oct  Dec    Hex    Abbr    Unicode  Control char  C Escape code   Name
0000000  000  0      00     NUL     ␀       ^@            \0              Null character
```

There's no difference, but the more idiomatic one is `'\0'`.

Putting it down as `char c = 0;` could mean that you intend to use it as a number (e.g. a counter). `'\0'` is unambiguous.

Comment: Does the C standard guarantee ASCII?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚胡海峰 No, I'm looking at the C99 standard and there's a few footnotes that mention ASCII with respect to implementing trigraphs and language implementations in ASCII and that's it. It is something that's implementation defined (bear in mind character sets such as IBM's EBCDIC). But I think you'd struggle to find a modern C implementation that doesn't rely on the ASCII character set. There's some useful information relating to this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251049/does-the-underlying-character-set-depend-only-on-the-c-implementation).

Comment: Yes, that's about what my read of the C99 gave as well. Thanks for that question, hadn't found it before.

Comment: Especilally, in C/C++, 0 or '\0' also used to terminate the string literal, ex: "abc\0"+"def" will be "abc". This is a place where '\0' is more visually

Answer (score 20):

`'\0'` is just an ASCII character. The same as `'A'`, or `'0'` or `'\n'`
If you write `char c = '\0`', it's the same as`char c = 0;`
If you write `char c = 'A'`, it's the same as `char c = 65`

It's just a character representation and it's a good practice to write it, when you really mean the NULL byte of string. Since `char` is in C one byte (integral type), it doesn't have any special meaning.

Comment: or 0b1000001, or 0101, that's not important in my answer. It's all number.

Comment: The character set doesn't have to be ASCII compatible, so 'A' does not have to be the same as 65. (E.g. EBCDIC is not ASCII compatible.) I don't know any character set that uses a non-zero value for the NUL character though.

Comment: @PaulGroke Thanks for the comment! I wonder if there is a character set that uses a non-zero value for the null character. To note: 1) as Nobilis has mentioned: the C standard does not guarantee ASCII; 2) as Keith Thompson has mentioned (useful to know): the signedness of plain char is implementation-defined (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62682671/9881330).

Answer (score 6):

Preferred choice is that which can give people reading your code an ability to understand how do you use your variable - as a number or as a character. 
Best practice is to use 0 when you mean you variable as a number and to use '\0' when you mean your variable is a character.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are already quite clear. I just share what I learned about this issue with a demo.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


char*
mystrcat(char *dest, char *src) {
    size_t i,j;
    for(i = 0; dest[i] != '\0'; i++)
        ;
    for(j = 0; src[j] != '\0'; j++)
        dest[i+j] = src[j];
    dest[i+j] = '\0';
    return dest;
}

int main() {
    char *str = malloc(20); // malloc allocate memory, but doesn't initialize the memory
    // str[0] = '\0'; 
    str[0] = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k <10; k++) {
        char s[2];
        sprintf(s, "%d", k);
        mystrcat(str, s);
    }
    printf("debug:%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program, I used `malloc` to initialize the pointer, but malloc doesn't initialize the memory. So after the `mystrcat` operation(which is nearly the same as the `strcat` function in glibc), the string may contain mess code(since the memory content is not initialized).

So I need to initialize the memory. In this case `str[0] = 0` and `str[0] = 0` both can make it work.