# terminating null char for 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

I have this nested loops working but I am printing extra char at the end because I don't know how to terminate the null char in 2D array. Here is the code:

```
char arr[100];
char twoDArray[100][100];
int y = 0, x = 0,  h= 10, w = 10,j=0;
for(y = 0; y <= h; y++)
{
  for(x = 0; x <= w; x++)
  {
    twoDArray[y][x] = arr[j];
    printf("%c", twoDArray[y][x]);
    j++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your data being initialized? This example shows only empty arrays being used. Also, did you mean to use `<=` in your for-loops? Usually that results in "extra" data being used because arrays in C are 0-based, and the max you'd be able to use is 0 to length-1.

Comment: For `twoDArray` since that's what I am trying to print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For null character in c following character is used.

```
'\0'
```

Check out following link.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm

[String termination - char c=0 vs char c='\0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955936/string-termination-char-c-0-vs-char-c-0)

Just compare in loop.

```
if(twoDArray[y][x]=='\0')
{
     break;
}
```

Comment: I know @RyanJ I  just had to wait 1 min for some reason. Thanks for the help anyway..!!