# Regular loop to Pointer loop conversion, how?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, pointers

```
SomeClass* stuff;
int N = 10;
stuff = new SomeClass[N];

Someclass* objectPtrDelete = null;

int i = 0;
for(Someclass* pointer = begin(); pointer != end(); pointer++)
{
    if(pointer->getSomeAttr() == randomPointer.getSomeAttr()){
        objectPtrDelete = pointer;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
    
// Shrinking the C-array with this for loop, shifting left
for (int j = i; j < N-1; j++)
    stuff[j] = stuff[j + 1];
```

Can the last loop be converted into a Pointer loop, if yes, how is this properly done? Note, the names are fictional i.e. something imaginary. I have implemented something similar, but, I would like to understand how can I convert the last loop to a pointer for loop that does the same operation.

Make this:

```
for (int j = i; j < N-1; j++)
    stuff[j] = stuff[j + 1];
```

Into a Pointer loop.

Comment: What is a "pointer loop"?

Comment: I do not know, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829566/for-loop-with-pointer-in-c. But, is it correct and is that the way you do it?

Comment: If you use pointers instead of indices not much changes. You simply need to figure out what you use as the condition (presumably something like `ptr != a + N` and make sure that you dereference correctly in the body.

Comment: @Albin M This  int[] a = new int[N] is not a valid C++ record.

Comment: I have a Pointer array, `SomeClass* stuff;` This is initiated: `stuff = new SomeClass[10];`

Comment: @UnholySheep, so you mean: `int* ptr = begin(); ptr != end(); ptr++` ?

Comment: You may read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic Also for your last comment it should be `std::begin(a)` and `std::end(a) - 1`.

Comment: You should seriously coinsider simply using a `std::vector<Someclass>`. If you initialize with `new` the size information  gets lost.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I am aware about STL and vectors. But, I want to do this with Array[] pure array approach.

Comment: _"pure array approach"_ That's `std::array<Someclass,N>` (with a `const N`) in c++.

Comment: I regular C-array. I heard this can be achieved. Therefore, I wanted to find out by doing. Anyway, I posted this to other forums as well. Just want to know, how I can convert the last for-loop into a pointer one. Which does the exact same things except with pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(edited to take into account your changes)

if I well understand what you want, having

> SomeClass* stuff;

you can replace

> ```
> for (int j = i; j < N-1; j++)
>    stuff[j] = stuff[j + 1];
> ```

by

```
for (SomeClass * p =  stuff + i; p < stuff + N-1; p++)
    *p = *(p + 1);
```

or to easily manages changes concerning the type :

```
for (auto p =  stuff + i; p < stuff + N-1; p++)
    *p = *(p + 1);
```

etc

Comment: @AlbinM I updated my answer, just the type and names changes

Comment: Bruno, will that still shrink the array?

Comment: Your code is confusing, where's `int j` now?

Comment: @AlbinM what you mean `shrink the array` ? its size is unchanged, you just move elements

Comment: @AlbinM  ah yes, sorry, I missed to replace a *j* by *p*, corrected

Answer (score 1):

For starters this construction (without an ending semicolon)

```
int[] a = new int[N]
```

is invalid in C++.

It should look like

```
int *a = new int[N];
```

If I have understood your question correctly you mean something like the following

```
for ( auto prev = a, next = a + 1; next != a + N; ++next )
{
    *prev++ = *next;
}
```

Comment: Vlad,  see my update. I apologize for not clarifying earlier.

Comment: @AlbinM What was changed?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow just the type of the array and the name of the variable